# Jquery add Unique identifier to Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm using the jQuery cycle plugin. However I need to add multiple instances of said code on a page. This will be passed through a loop. This means I have to add a unique identifier to the function. I'm really not that comfortable with JavaScript in general.

**Below is the original code**.

```
jQuery.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager, currSlideIndex) { 
    jQuery(pager).find('li').removeClass('mini-activeLI') 
        .filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex+')').addClass('mini-activeLI'); 
};
```

This is what I was trying.
Where `+unique+` could be generated by PHP `rand()`:

```
jQuery.fn.cycle.updateActivePagerLink = function(pager, currSlideIndex+unique+) { 
    jQuery(pager).find('li').removeClass('mini-activeLI') 
        .filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex+unique++')').addClass('mini-activeLI'); 
};
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Even if you generate *unique* with PHP, it would not work as a loop. The best approach would be to randomise the loop with javascript itself.

Comment: @Michael - don't understand what you need.. where is the loop?

Comment: I did not think it's important to add all code, The loop is a simple WordPress loop. If I was to add 2 cylce instances on a page I need a unique identifier for each cylce's pagination . I'm actually able to get this to work if I use this in php >> function(pager, currSlideIndex<?php echo $id ?>)

Comment: @Michael so it's working now, or is there anything else you need?

Comment: For my implementation I need to pass a VAR to the script, this is where I need assistance ::: Unfortunately I cant use my PHP workaround :::

Comment: @Michael see my answer.. judging from what you said so far it should work. Also, use "@" to notify people you posted new comment I get notification only because this question is in my favorites.

Comment: @Shdow Wizard ::: THX for posting the script but I have it as you posted, I need to be able to replace <?php echo $id ?> with a VAR :::As I now call the script in the header ::: As soon as I attempt this nothing works eg. currSlideIndex+unique* ::: Must have something to do with function() :::

Comment: @Shdow Wizard ::: THX again did not work though ::: I resorted to adding the jQuery inline (inside php file) ::: Will just have to work for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused about how to get a variable from PHP to Javascript, you can do something like:

```
<?php 
    $unique = 123456;
    echo "<script>var unique = $unique;</script>";
?>
```

Which will give you a global variable you can use from inside other script tags just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function(pager, currSlideIndex<?php echo $id ?>) { 
    jQuery(pager).find('li').removeClass('mini-activeLI') 
        .filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex<?php echo $id ?>+')').addClass('mini-activeLI'); 
};
```

Edit: to pass it as variable have this:

```
<?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>var _sliderIndexId = " + $id + ";</script>" ?>
```

And then:

```
function(pager, currSlideIndex) { 
        jQuery(pager).find('li').removeClass('mini-activeLI') 
            .filter('li:eq(' + (currSlideIndex + "") + (_sliderIndexId + "")) +')').addClass('mini-activeLI'); 
    };
```

Not sure about the PHP syntax but that's the general idea: have PHP output the id as global JS variable then use that variable in the function.